# My spring boot application was running fine but when I dockerized it I got File not Found error

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

[I don't know what I'm getting this error when I dockerized my spring-boot application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwdKc.png)

this is my Dockerfile
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04aeh.png)

Answer (score 0):

In your Spring Boot application, from what I can see your `BookingController` is missing. Make sure you have the file present and build your image accordingly.

For your `Dockerfile`, try to change `add` to `ADD`, as it seems your target files are not been copied into the image built.

Answer (score 0):

First, I wonder is your application working on your IDE?

Second, I think you make sure to build and package.
It is not sure to exists a jar file in your target folder.
You always have to build and check by yourself.

Make the build process automatic.

How about using this Dockerfile?

```
FROM maven:3.8.6-openjdk-18-slim as MAVEN_BUILD

WORKDIR /build

COPY pom.xml .

RUN mvn dependency:go-offline

COPY src ./src

RUN mvn package -Dmaven.test.skip=true

FROM openjdk:18-alpine

WORKDIR /app

ARG JAR_FILE=*.jar

COPY --from=MAVEN_BUILD /build/target/${JAR_FILE} ./app.jar

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]
```

If maven or openjdk version not matched, check this site.

- https://hub.docker.com/_/maven
- https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk